# How do I prevent program from running BOTH an IF and ELSE statement with C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, range

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int hun;
    std::cout << "Please pick a number between 1 and 100 \n";
    std::cin >> hun;
    if (hun > 50)
    {
        std::cout << "Your number is greater than 50. ";
    }
    if (hun < 50)
    {
        std::cout << "Your number is less than 50. ";
    }
    if (hun > 100) 
    {
        std::cout << "Pick a number LESS than 100. ";
    }
    else { std::cout << "Your number is equal to 50. "; }

    return 0;
}
```

If I run it without the:

`std::cout << "Pick a number LESS than 100. ";`

then the program works as expected. However it doesn't work if I include it. For example if I input "13" I get both the message "Your number is less than 50, AND your number is equal to 50" ?? I don't understand why it is still executing the else statement if my IF statement was already met. This isn't an issue ONLY if I removes that 3rd IF statement.

I cannot figure out why it is just that line that is messing up. I seem to have everything written correctly, and I didn't forget the curly brackets. So why is this happening?

I'm sure it's a simple mistake. It's my first week coding and I'm doing it on my own with no outside help, so I don't have anyone to go to for silly questions like this.

While I'm here, how do I get the program to say something like "You have entered an invalid response. " When the user inputs a word or a letter? I thought about doing something like:

```
int word;
word = 1-100;
if (hun = word) or (hun != int?)
```

(But that will only subtract 100 from 1 giving me -99 and not the range, I really do not even know where to begin with this)

Comment: If a compiler generates a code which executes both _if_ and _else_ statements - change the compiler.

Comment: @scopchanov I'm getting this result in powershell, what do you recommend I use instead?

Comment: This was an expression of my doubt that any decent contemporary compiler will do what you've described in the title.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement [`if-else if- else`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_if_else_statement.htm) statements:

```
if (hun > 100) 
{
    std::cout << "Pick a number LESS than 100. ";
}
else if (hun > 50)
{
    std::cout << "Your number is greater than 50. ";
}
else if (hun < 50)
{
    std::cout << "Your number is less than 50. ";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Your number is equal to 50. ";
}
```

The reason why the original code didn't work is that the `else` was only linked to the last `if`. So if a number satisfied one of the earlier `if` statements but not the last `if` it would go to both the `if` it satisfied and the `else` as the last `if` was not satisfied.

Additionally you must reorder it so that the more extreme cases are first. Otherwise if `hun` is more that one hundred but you have the condition `hun > 50` then it will go to that `if-else` and then skip the rest.

Comment: @GBlodgett Huh, I didn't even know about these! So why does it work if I have two "if" statements, but if I add a 3rd or more I need to use the "else if"? I mean, why do the two "if" statements still work with the "else" is my question.

Comment: maybe you can update the reason of reorder in answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   if (hun >= 0 && hun < 50){
        std::cout << "Your number is less than 50. ";
    }
    else if (hun == 50){
        std::cout << "Your number is equal to 50. ";
    }
    if (hun > 50 && hun <= 100) {
        std::cout << "Your number is less than 50. ";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "you ve entered invalid number " << hun << " . supported range is [0 - 100]";
    }
```

Comment: Ah, so two ampersands when I want to specify a range?

Comment: @Zii , && - implements logical and, || - logical or. you can read here about c++ operators https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B